# auto expand div height

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
<html><head><title>Test</title>
<style>
.main{width:600px;border:1px solid red; }
.main .left{background:lightblue; width:100px;clear:both; float:left;}
.main .right{margin-left:100px;background:lightyellow; }
</style>
    </head><body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">
    title
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div id="item">item</div>
        <div id="item">item</div>
        <div id="item">item</div>
        <div id="item">item</div>
        <div id="item">item</div>
        <div id="item">item</div>
        <div id="item">item</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

How to change the CSS to make the page display like the dialog shows?

PS,I think it's a way that to make the "left" div's height auto expand when the height of the "right" div or parent div expand, but I don't know how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Expand child DIV height to parent's height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a very simple solution. Use css attribute `display: table-cell;` in `.left{}` & `.right{}` style like this:

```
    .left, .right { 

         display: table-cell;
         width:100px; 
         vertical-align:middle; 
         text-align:center;

     }
```

See the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/qcCPG/3/

Comment: Thanks! It works and it's necessary to add DOCTYPE definition for the html document.

Answer (score 0):

Here is different totally style that works:

```
.main{width:600px;border:1px solid red; height:auto; position:relative }
.main > div {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
.main .left{background:lightblue; width:100px; height: 100%; }
.main .right{margin-left:5px; background:lightyellow; height: 100% }
```

You may want to go through this [CSS tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) at w3schools.

Comment: Thanks very much,it's one step closer to what I want. Hope it will be like that the right div's height is auto and expands when having more content,and the left div's height will auto expands to be equal to the right.

Comment: Now i get that the left div'height can be auto expand only when the main div's height could be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **FLEX** or combine **FLEX** with **GRID**

```
/******************************************
    1. FLEX
*******************************************/
.main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.left {
    width: 30%;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.right { 
    flex-grow: 1;
}
/******************************************
    2. FLEX with GRID
*******************************************/
.main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 1fr;
}
.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

have fun