# Jquery.css performing unwanted flickering effect on IE and Webkit (Chrome, Safari) but Firefox is ok

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, webkit, parallax

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){    
      Topo =  $(window).scrollTop();
      ObjScrollASoda.css({
          'marginTop' : (Topo - 800)+'px'
      });
   });
});
```

(note: ObjScrollASoda is the jquery object for the can)

Here is a fiddle replicating the issue of it made by Trufa:
http://jsfiddle.net/VcvJe/1/

In the blue section, there is a blue can that will "scroll" with the page making a parallax-like effect. Here is the problem, as I'm just setting the css while the user scrolls the page, only in Chrome (and other webkit browsers) it happens the can to show a flickering effect (unwanted). And I noticed it doesn't happend in Firefox.
Does anyone knows how to avoid this "flickering" effect ??

Here is a video explaining better what's happening : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqDmOx6XY-M

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: If you want to, I would try to set up a jsfiddle with as an example, it is easier to test upon...

Comment: Here is a similar example I made http://jsfiddle.net/VcvJe/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I viewed your **YouTube video** and the best method is to set **`position:fixed`** when not moving the ***Azul Can*** or set **`position:absolute`** when moving it.

That said, this [**SO Member's Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5903078/1195891) created a simple plugin to do this with `.scrollTop();` method.

That same ***SO Question*** page has many other useful answers too.

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle with Azul Can for Chrome**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4JnS/show/)

View that **jsFiddle** without the `/show/` as seen in the **Address Bar** to access the **Edit Page**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not fully understanding the question, but it sounds like you want the can to remain where it is as the user scrolls down the page. I think the flickering effect you describe is caused by the re-positioning of the can as the user scrolls.

Would using `position: fixed` be an acceptable alternative? Please see http://jsfiddle.net/VcvJe/8/ for a demo.

With a fixed position, the element is never re-positioned so there is no flicker. However, it will not work in IE<7 as there is no supportfor `position: fixed`.