# "Sticky" Scroll Positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Is there any way to frame content based on scroll position; Whenever a user scrolls past a certain marker point the page is pushed (locked) to a certain position (slide) guiding the user to view the content on that slide (the page is based on https://github.com/richardshepherd/Parallax-Scrolling/). There would be multiple marker points so the user is guided to view the content on the slides.

Answer (score 5):

yes.  There is a nifty little jquery plugin that handles this: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

or you can reference this previous post dealing with the same subject matter: [Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point)

Comment: I just used scrollToFixed on my most recent project, worked like a charm.  Also used something similar to your second post, which also worked for me as well.

Comment: @htmlMaster Sorry I was a bit unclear, what I meant was guided scroll; as a user scrolls past a certain point the .scrollTop() smoothly jumps to a point to display the content.