# jquery on scroll fixed position

Tags: jquery, slide, fixed, absolute

how to make div block, witch will start scrolling on one point in site with scrollbar (position: fixed) and ends scrolling in other point.

http://postimage.org/image/oka20h80z/

Block starts scrolling on first black line and end scrolling on second black line and stays

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use scrolltop. something like

```
if( scrollTop() > 500 ){
  selector.css('position', 'fixed');
}
if( scrollTop() > 1000 ){
  selector.css('position', 'relative');
}
```

something like this. If it has scrolled more than 500px make it pasition fixed. if it has scrolled more than 1000 do something.