# Element scrolls into position fixed, then scrolls out of fixed position again, with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position

I am trying to recreate an effect like the one found on the front page of artsy.net

They have a stream of blog-style posts in a vertical scroll layout; but what's special about it, is that the meta data and text content from the blog post scrolls into position fixed once it reaches the top of the screen, while the different image contents from the post keeps scrolling. Once the bottom of the image contents has been reached, the fixed position contents "scrolls out of" fixed position, and the next blog post scrolls up. It all works very seemlessly and feels genuinely natural.

I have tried a similar effect with a navigation menu getting position fixed (using a solution found in this question: [Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point) )
but what's different about the solution I am now looking for, is that the effect needs to be able to handle dynamic content, ie content generated with wordpress by non-web-savvy contributors.

Thank you very much for any help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution on my own! I found this very helpful and extremely easy to implement plugin called Stickem : https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem

So for anyone else looking for an answer, here's your help :)