# Fixed column, under navbar - css

Tags: css, scroll, multiple-columns, navbar

Behance has a column on the right side of the page, that once you scroll past a certain point, becomes fixed.

i.e. go to this page then scroll down to see example
http://www.behance.net/gallery/minke/7133409

Does anyone know how they do this?  Is it with CSS and AJAX?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in the jquery way. Check this [Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point).

Or you can go with a jquery plugin [jQuery-Stickem](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem).