# A portion of the page (right/left) stays in place as you scroll down but unsticks at a certain point

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, floating

First here is an example of what I want to do

http://www.nbcphiladelphia.com/news/local/Tripathi-Body-Found-River-204452461.html?_osource=SocialFlowTwt_PHBrand

A portion of this page (right side) is initiallyt just part of the page and then it stays in place once you've scrolled down enough when it comes into view. But after you scroll down past a certain point, it unsticks and slides up again. I would like to do this with a menu I have in mind. Thanks.

Comment: So what is the question, what have you created so far, and what problem are you struggling with? Other than that, I commend your enthusiasm.

Comment: [jquery-scroll-follow](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-follow/) is a jQuery plugin that does this and has an [example](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/sf-example-3.html) that describes what you are after.

Comment: That site (nbcphiladelphia) uses jQuery. Look in the [source code for `nbc_v3_major.js`](http://www.nbcphiladelphia.com/includes/nbc_v3_major.js?r=2013-04-25F). There is a section starting with `/* CODE FOR RIGHT RAIL FOLLOWING DOWN THE PAGE */`.

Comment: Get this idea ..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not experienced in coding, I'm just used to copying and pasting jQuery other people have already done so Jason and user2234261 gave me the most helpful answers.