# Prevent fixed div from moving past a certain

Tags: javascript, html, css

This turned out to be more difficult than I anticipated.  I have a `#content` area, a `#left`, and a `#right` with a `div#sidebar` inside the `#right` element.

Currently, the fixed sidebar scrolls down to overlap with the footer.  How can I get it to terminate at a higher point?

http://jsfiddle.net/uzbNL/

I attempted to implement this [previous stack overflow accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point), but had no luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzbNL/5/). I've added a jQuery listener on page scroll. whenever the page reaches a certain scroll I add new class `fixed` to the `#sidebar` causing it to stay fixed on the bottom of `#right` container.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
      if($(this).scrollTop()>1750)
          $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed')
      else
          $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed')
    });    
});
```

CSS

```
#sidebar.fixed{position:absolute;top:auto;bottom:0px;}
```