# How do i make a fixed positioned sidebar but only when it reaches the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need my sidebar to be scrollable along with the rest of the page until it reaches the end of the content in the sidebar, then it needs to be fixed. A good example of this is Facebooks right sidebar.

Is the only way to use javascript or can it be done without?

If javascript is the only out, can someone explain this relatively simple or refer to a tutorial? I'm not that strong in js.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please do provide a jsFiddle in the future it's free and it helps other users

Comment: I think this does roughly what you're asking but may need slight tweaking:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5903087/717383

Answer (score 1):

I just positioned the `<div id="box"></div>` fixed positioning to the body which has a position of relative applied. Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2qwEs/

Comment: thanks, I was going of a tangent for a different problem all fixed now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't see how this would solve the problem stated?