# How can I make a div stop scrolling up when it's bottom is reached?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to do something like the 3rd column of Facebook home page from left (where ads appear). When you scroll the page upward, all three columns scroll, but then 3rd column stops scrolling. How to do that? Can it be done with CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop jQuery fixed position scrolling when bottom of scrolling element reaches end of parent element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261460/stop-jquery-fixed-position-scrolling-when-bottom-of-scrolling-element-reaches-en)

Answer (score 0):

I think Facebook does it with a mix of javascript/css
When user is scrolling down, they change position attribute to right col element to fixed.

```
position: fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sticyjs puigin
 http://stickyjs.com/

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0});
  });
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

In the bootstrap world, this is called [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix). Basically, you're listening to the scroll event with javascript and changing the styling (css) based on breakpoints (specific scroll position).

To answer the second question, I don't believe it can be done solely with CSS.