# fixed position for a div inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i was working on woocommerce site.**[My Site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/SharQ/shop/team-sharq-black/)** . The single product page has a control generator with a number of drop down options.So when a user selects each options he cannot see the changes happening at the top.So i position the image div as fixed.As follows.

```
.single-product .images{position:fixed;}
```

this made the image fixed but it is floating till down the page.I only need it just before the description/review tabs starts.Is there any other css or any js/jquery solutions to solve this .Please help.Thanks!!

Comment: You need to use absolute instead....

Comment: thats not working.Can u giv me the code please

Comment: to clarify.. You want the image to float down the page but stop just before the tabs..? or you want it not floating and located right beofre the tabs?

Comment: i want it floating down the page but stop just before the tabs

Comment: Well, it's not that simple.. You would need use js, basically calculate the offset top of your tabs.. you could use position fixed on the images, and on either a scroll event or interval calculate the relation between the images offset to tabs offset and at desired point change your images position to absolute with the desired offsets.. Ofcourse if you wanted to do the job right, you'd need to consider what happens on window resize including reducing the size of the images etc..

Comment: oops .. any links to refer plesae!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your website environment, you need something like this:

```
var images = jQuery('.images');

jQuery.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = jQuery(window);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos - $this.height()
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 'auto' //earlier it was 0
            });
        }
    });
};

images.followTo(jQuery('#myTab').offset().top - images.height());
```

You may need to re-position the elements a bit, but the script will work on your website, as I tested with firebug.

I have note written this script, the script attributed to:  [Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point)

Let me know if you can take it forward from here :)

Comment: jus copy paste this to my file?

Comment: yes, you can copy-paste. But where will you paste? I believe you are using Wordpress+Woocommerce.

Comment: You can enqueue script in function.php of your theme.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: hi that worked .. but the problem now is it gone over the top.. wat can be done??

Comment: top: 0 i changed it to top: 324px but bottom part is overflowing :(

Comment: I've made changes in script, please do rest yourself and avoid discussions in comments.