# scrolltofixed will not work on tumblr page

Tags: javascript, jquery

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the scrolltofixed code to work on my tumblr page. I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point) and [here](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed), but nothing seems to work. My tumblr page is http://htmltest004.tumblr.com - I'm trying to get it to work on my .navigation div class. I was originally trying to do it with a div id, and switched to a div class to see if that made any difference (which it didn't). Please note, I don't know *anything* about JavaScript - only CSS and HTML. All the information I have came from the two linked sources. If you guys could help me, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not used the plugin JS source. After correcting the path, and executing it again, it still didn't work, but it turned out that the section of .wrapper was messing with things, so I removed it.