# How do I have a image stay fixed on the page but have a text overlaid move?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to figure out how I'd go about coding something similar to this website: http://www.nataliads.cl/ and how to have the text scroll down for a certain length, but not have the picture to move.

Comment: post your code or a fiddle and we can we help.

Comment: I have this resource that shows what I'm attempting to do: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html Just having difficulty now with figuring out where all the specific code goes.

Comment: Ok cool... that's a great example but we need your code or a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to keep a **floating block of text or image above the images moving underneath**, you can use css "position:fixed;".

```
    .floating-block{
      position: fixed;
      top: 25%;
      right: 25%;
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid red;
      background-color:white;
    }
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/NYCguyJason/vxcj31zj/

**Or the opposite...** (because your wording is a bit confusing)
If you are trying to have **fixed position image which does not move while the rest of the page scrolls**, try this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/NYCguyJason/4n9ab0x6/1/

```
    .fixedBackground {
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    }
```

**Edits**
**Edits**
**EDITS Per your new comments **

Per your comments, here are some additional ideas to get closer to what you described:

**1. Pure CSS:** 
Set the "z-index"s so that certain elements stay on top of others. (highest z-index stays on top. You must set the "position" to something to use "z-index")

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/NYCguyJason/vxcj31zj/1/

```
.fullwidthblock {   /* this is the first background */
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.floating-block{  /* this is the floating block */
  position: fixed;
  z-index:2;
}
.stayOnTop{     /* this is for all blocks further down the page that should always stay on top*/
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
}
```

**?Do you have jquery on your site?**

**2. Custom Javascript or Jquery:** 
Keep the element Fixed, until you scroll to a certain point, and then make it scroll up with you. 
There's an answer here: (but it seems to be using an older version of jquery)
[Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point)

**3. A full Jquery plugin:**

**Sticky Kit**
http://leafo.net/sticky-kit
--Seems okay

**ScrolTo Fixed**
http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/
--This looks like your best bet, so I updated the jsfiddle to show you this option:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/NYCguyJason/bn9ekcds/7/

<!-- grab jquery  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!-- grab plugin script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed/master/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>

<!-- trigger the plugin -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$('.floating-block').scrollToFixed({
  marginTop: 80,  //how far from the top of the window to start
//  limit: $($('.stayOnTop')).offset().top
  limit: 550   //when to make the fixed element start scrolling up
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Okay so your first example makes sense and is exactly what I want to do, but is there a way to stop it moving at a certain point as I don't want it to scroll into other areas of the website.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. To get the rest of the effect from your example, you can try one of these 3 ideas:
1. Pure CSS:  (easiest option: hide the "fixed" element under the next section by giving it a higher "z-index")
2. Custom Javascript or Jquery: to keep the element Fixed, until you scroll to a certain point, and then make it scroll up with you.
3. A full Jquery plugin: I found one option (http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/), but I'm sure there's plenty more.

I'll make edit my answer above with code examples...

Comment: I have a long answer for you with links to examples, but it's blocking me from posting an answer with more than 2 links, because this is a new account and I have less than 10 reputation points.. (i guess it's a spambot protection.)
**I think if you approve the answer I gave, it will give me enough points to post the extra code and example links to help you out.**

Comment: I have enough point now to post my full instructions. See the edits above. Good luck with your project!