# Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point? ~ Reverse

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

In this StackOverflow question: [Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point?scrlybrkr=88119532) you can find jQuery for stopping an element thats going top to bottom and stopping said element on its way to the bottom somewhere in the middle of the page.

I don't have much experience with jQuery and was hoping the following code could be reversed to do the same if it was scrolling bottom to top and stopping halfway.

Thanks!

```js
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#f').followTo(250);
```

```css
#f {
    background:#ace;
    padding:20px;
    width:200px;
    position:fixed; top:0; left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="f">
    I'm going to follow you only so far...
</div>
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
```

Comment: Is this what you're going for? http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/11018/

Comment: no, the element is at the bottom of the page, acting as a fixed footer, and i want the Jquery to stop it halfway up the page.