# is there any function called followFrom() in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script which I found where it takes a **image id** and lets the image scroll till a set limit here - (2550 px), is there any function called followFrom in jQuery where is tells the image to follow from a certain pixel to the limit of **2550 px** ?

Like **followTo** sets the max limit of fixed image so, is there **followFrom** which makes the fixed image move from a starting pixel to limit ?

```js
var windw = this;
           $.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
             var $this = this,
                 $window = $(windw);

             $window.scroll(function(e){
              console.log($window.scrollTop());
               if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
                 $this.css({
                   position: 'absolute',
                   top: pos
                 });
               } 
               else
               {
                 $this.css
                 ({
                   position: 'fixed',
                   top: 100,
                   width:260.25,
                   bottom: 50
                 });
               }
             });
           };
           $('#bottle').followTo(2550);
```

```css
.div{
  width:100%;
  height:4000px;
  background-color:grey;
}
#bottle
{
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <img id="bottle" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxATEBUSExISEhUVEBUSEhUYFxgVEhYVFxEWFxUSFhUYHSggGBolHRUVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGy4gHSUrLS03LSstKy0wLS0tLS0tLS0rLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0rKy0tKy0tLy0tKy0tLS0tLTUrLf/AABEIAT4AnwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAACAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwIFBgQHAQj/xABMEAABAwECCQUMCAMGBwAAAAABAAIDEQQFBhIhMUFRYXGxEyIzgZEjMkJScnOCobLB0fAHFGJ0krPS4RWjtCU1U2OiwhY0Q4OT4vH/xAAaAQACAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwIEBQEG/8QALBEAAgEDBAECBQQDAAAAAAAAAAECAxExBBIhQVETIhQyYXHwQoGhsTNS8f/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A9xQhCABCEIAEIQgAQuG8b4s0FBNPFETmDnAOO5uc9SqpMOLvGaUu3Rv4luVMjRqS5jFv9iLkllmjQsjL9Ithb/jO3M+JC5X/AEoWEf8ATtH4WfrTloq7/QyPqw8m4QsGfpUsP+Fafws9718Z9K9gJyxWpu0sj90hXfgdR/oznrQ8m9QsXH9KF1+FJKzfFIfYBVpYMN7smIDLZBU5Gte7k3E6g2ShrsSZUKkPmi1+xNTi8M0CEISiQIQhAAhCEACEIQAIQhAAhCEAeIYbWet52l3+Yzr7hGqZzaaT1GmjaCtFhqP7QtHnG/lMWfk+HAr1mn/xR+y/ozp/M/uckvlO7AdG8LkkB8Y6fBGgeUuqb48AuWTP+L2VaivqJZDF+0c/ij9S+PA0Y2auUj4KXxHBfP0niVK31OXEujNDX36qrjnFW5hozDWD8F3zOybyOBXDL3vUODlR1PgdTP0pgL/ddh+4Wb8hivFR4C/3XYfuFm/IYrxeXn8zNIEIQogCEIQAIQhAAhCEACEIQB4zhqf7QtHlt/JYs/J8OBXtGFl02aSzzSSQxue2CQteWjlAQwkUfnz7V5bZLkjkB50jaEUy1GbavR6PUqdJcYsjK1NSNKptffJnZvjwC5ZM/wCL2VsH4ItNO7SZa+LqH2Sq+8cFsQVErjnz00+ir0K8XwivKvBK7M78RwUHPAHoniVorowW5Z1HSubQVyU0DaF0zYDRtA7tLm1N+C7PURT29nI14SjuT4MY99T1jgVzzOGL1Dg5Pv8As/IyuY1ziBTKc/e7N69p+jrBC7nXfZrQ+ywySvha97njlOfrAfUN6gKLP1lX047n2XtOt/KNLgL/AHXYfuFm/IYrxfAKZAvq883d3NAEIQuACEIQAIQhAAhCEACEJdonYxpe9wa1oJc4mgAGckoAzn0jXC+2WF0TJRGWuE3OJEb8QE4jyKkDKHVpkLWleZXE2WJmLI98b6muM3HZQZueMn+pbO88OrNMXRUe2OtMYg8+hyGgygbD16hzWb6pIQGSipzDGFew5Vraac6VPbJcZMzU7asuLMpv424OLaxPxdIdStQDmyrpa2S0tIHJsoK5yVq4roYRna7e0FfDcTfBEY3NA4J/xdNYVmUnoqjzyvBibPLJZnEnk35CM5HuSp71dIyrpooRUimMCcn4Stl/w0K1PJn0Krr/AISwCnNbTU0BSlraebXfk5S0M48PHj8Z4Tf9hc6SkPKTYwBLmsLWY1TXnHJmpp0r2f6G8HZbJYSZHtJnk5YMaatj5obQnNj83LTUBlouO/bBZw2rpg12ipFOzSqS4cOPqT8R1ZYS7nAZxreyuSuw59iVqKktRT2x/wCl+hL05Wa4PZELmu23xTxNlheJGPFWuHrBGcEZiDlBXSsZq3DNIEIQuACEIQAIQhAAhC+OcAKnIBlJ0IA+SSBoLiaACpKyF+XgJ+ZTudcx000lfL8vgyuxGGjAe06z8/tXMVylS2+55KVatu9qwIFzQHwGdbWn3KxsFytbzg2Mbmhp9QXRYLOXFW7YSNCnOq1xcXCmnycf1d2pKks8mgHtHxVninUgJaqMY6aZVss8mkHt/dMls7joVg5fYqakOo8h6SXBQz3Xjd9iHeMbiqW8sFoKE4jTrAaG8FunNFKKttEdDRdVaRF00jDXJbZbtkLowX2dzu6M06sbY7bppQ6Ker3dbo542yxODmuFQeII0Ealgb0sdOcBkOcKuuS832GXHZV0Dj3aIaP8xm0cMmojtSHqK/f9k6dXY7PB6whKstoZIxsjHBzXAOa4ZiCmqkXAQhCABCEIAFlMKr5y8iw+Wdvi9WnbuKtsI71FnhJB57uazfTK7qHrprXnbHlxqdKtaelf3Mqamrb2o7YRXbVd8EVXUGXQdp2LlsmRpd6Ld5GU9Q9ZCu7ls/hH5KsTlZFaCuy0ssIa2nanhRCkFTZaR8kORJClKcqiF1HQcoVplU3Jbl0GdFUi0x1G3QpwnJuX1yiRZSTNrUFZy3QYrqaNC1dujoa6+Kpryhxm7QnxYmSF4I3z9Wk5J57hI7JXNFITkOxjjkOo0Okr0deOyNBBBFQRQg6RpC3eA18mWIwvdWSGgqc74jXk3nWchadra6VCvC63Ifp6n6WadCEKqWgQhCAPLcM715W2ujB5sPcxqrkLz2kD0FxRTNHhBZ+Rr32mZ2cunlcRtMrieKsYIXAirSRpp8QtqNNKKRizm3Js0LbWzmNqTQYxyaXZeGKOpaWx21gYAA7XmHxWZsEsRd3pacgyjsFepaSNzdYSakUThNnYLb9kqX1w+J6/2SmgawvpbkVfbHwO3SEvt5r3nr/ZKdejvEHapujXO+JNjGHghKpNdjP4o7xB2pjLYT4NOtc4iXRDGuSjDpBGc2+WSbbi2vMJ6/2SZb3P+GeKZLGuSVo1jtXFGL6OynJCLRfAORzXDqHxXG+8YjnJHUfcuqWWGmUgHWDUdYVZaJYjoL9zU1U4+BXqSKy0WiPGNHDhxXy5r0+r22CWvNMghk1GOUhuXYH4jvRK4Lzsjy6rY3AHMD8SqG9bHII3muLzHHIcuQVGbcpKnF8XJKVnc/SCEuzPLmNcc5aCesVTFkmsCEIQB5fh9dUNlnZMwECd0jnNzgPBaXEbDjk00HfkrrJaWHM4cD6104e3wy2TCKIZIHyMxjme6oDqDQAWUB0rPxQub3wpw7Vr0k9i3ZMmq473twbe6Dzq7a+paBk4OdoWIuYHQSNxI4LQQ2lw0135UmpC7J05cF60x+KOwL65kZGYdiq47YdQT22zZ60lxY5SQ51jjPg9hI4FQN1wnwXfjf8AqX0WvYpi17PX+yLz8nfZ4Em6IPFd/wCST9Sj/DIRma78b/1J7rV9n1/slOtTvFH4j8EXn5/k41Dx/Ao2CLxa7y48SlmyxjMxg9EKb53/AGR1E+8LmdI/S4dTacSVL3eSLt4G41MgApqoKLlkUZXE+EeHBc0g69+XiupEGzjvjR861DBi44rXOWy5WMbjObofzgA07M9VG84yWggKODl/sscxdI2rHgNeRnaMauPTTTV/8MrPa9uSMXHct2D1hC+Ar6s81AQhCAPBbL00nnZPzHK/gVFZx3V218h/nSD3K9gW1IxkX92WePFysBza26PskKzbZoToeNxrxVfdZ5g3DgFYsVSbdyxBKxL6lHoc/rAK+Gx6nV3invTmprUu7GqKOYWQ6wpCzO2LpCkFHczu1HGbO7YlmB+pvafgrByW5G4HFFe6B/2e0/BINnfpc3qaeNVYuSHqSkyDijgfZ/tH1fBJdC0a+0ldsi5pFJNkGjjto5hWKvrvT5J4LbWzvD86Vi73HMfsYeIHvTqWRNTB7lYeiZ5tvshPSLD0TPNt9kJ6zXk1kCEIXDp4VGO69cn9RKrqBVBHdR6f9RKreBbLMbs0dxtrG3yR7IVq2HaqrB7o2+SOAV21U5vktQwREZUwFNqic6XcYj6FIKIUguEgcluTHJbkAxLkh6e5IcFJEGc8i5pF1PadSQ6IqSFM4bZ3h+dKx15jucvmv97FsrcKNPzpWPvAdzm8wfzI06llCamGe22Homebb7IT0iw9EzzbfZCes55NZAhCFw6eHyDuo8l39RKrWFVkw7q3yHf1Eqs4Fs9GO8mjwe6NvkjgFdtVJg90bfJHAK7aqVTJZhgY1ROdSaonOljT6FIKIUgg6DktyY5LcgGJcoN0qblBuldIMW9JenPSXrpBlXeHeu3+9ZC3Duc33c/mRrX3h3rt/vWStfRz/d3e2xWKeUInhntNh6Jnm2+yE9IsPRM8232QnrOeTVQIQhcOniVo6VvkO/PlVlAq209K3yHfnyKygWx0Y7yaTB/o2+SOAV01U1xDmDyRwCuWqnUyWYYGNUTnUmqJzpY0+hSCiFIIOg5LcmOS3IBiXKDdKm5QbpXSDFvSXpz0l66QZV3h3rt/vWTtXRT/AHd3ttWsvDvXb/esnauin+7u9pqsUxEz2iw9EzzbfZCekWHomebb7IT1nPJqoEIQuHTxO09K3yHfnSKxgVdaT3Vvku/OkVjAtjox3k0t0uo3s4BWzJQqe7e87OCsGKpNcliD4O5pXw50lqaEuw1EgpBRCkFwkDktyY5LcgGJcoN0qblBuldIMW9JenPSXrpBlXeHeu3+9ZS09FP93d7TVq7w712/3rJ2o9yn8wfaarFMRM9osPRM8232QnpFh6Jnm2+yE9ZzyaqBCELh08Pe7uo9MfzpFawKmY6sp2OeP5rlcwLZeDHeTR3b3nZwVgxV92d586lYMVSeSxDA9qa1KamtS2NRIKQUQpBRJA5LcmOS3IBiXKDdKm5IeukGD0h6+SFc0ikkLbOa8O9d86VkLce5TbYiPWFrbZ3hWOvN3c5NrDwT6eRM8Ht9h6Jnm2+yE9IsPRM8232QnrOeTVQIQhcOnhLG0tErdU8reyRw9yu4FaYa4ONhkda2HmPkrI2nevecrtoc7sLtRyVFkla7MQdxWvGanFNGRODhKzNHdLqsVmxUtwO5lOtXTFXnkdDA9qa1KamtSmORIKQUQpBRJA5LcmOS3IBiXJD09yQ9SRBnPIuaRdMi5pFJCmcduPMKxd8HmO8k+yVrr1lAZlNPmiTgtg79bk5VxpDHIMbXI4UdyY1NzVOo0GeobCSj7ngW4uT2o9Os7KMaNTQOwJiELONUEIQgDzD6QMIJJpHWSLFDI30kPhPe3QDmAB0a259eUs7CDlBB9alDLj2iV/jTyO/FK4+9XcbARQgEbVswiqcUkY85OcrsbcFukZQA4w1OGMOonKOorVxXiw99HTa0+4qmum7ojnDm6iDXtB+KuBdfiyNdsPNKRUcWxsFKx0stcR8cbwDwTROzxvcuE2CUeD2UK+cm4ZwUnauhu5otGvGsdqkHDWFWAKQXNpJSLBzhrHakunZ4ze1cyg4oUQchslobrPUCeAXK+1DQ1x6gOJXx8rfGHaEkvBzBx3NdTtpRSURbkV9931yOLzMYuJpV1KUpU5toVFLhBM7Nit3DL/qqm4btcGxOpTnuGWmkA/7VnbNjOIAyk6BlV6jSg4J2K1SUrjLdaXPdznF281V7gThU6yyiF4BhlkaHa2OdRokB1d7Uahsy0dvs7mAFwptyH1j5yKnthqDuPBdlTjJbXgjCbi9yP0qhKssmNG13jMa7tAKasM2wQhCAPALqFXnyj7RWlhBGQ5FU3BFS0yDxXyDrEhb8Vf2sc8eSOJWzJ82MdLi5bXUOb87VZsVbdfe9ismKpPI+GB7CmgpTU1qUxyJBfcQagvgUguEiDo2+KOwJZhb4rewJ7ktyLnGhLkh6e5IepIizGfSO7uMQ08sT1BhrxCrcEYW4hkfXK7FyZ6CmQbzwX3De1iWYMblbECK/aJGN2UA6ium5IsWzsGwu7XE+9aUVtopFOo+S1viyxSWZ2KAKAmtMuQaVkMG7I2U2hjgCRY5sWuWjw3I7eKrU8rSOUa4z20oOKpsCI+62t+hsEw6yW/ApV3GLOwtJo9juj/l4fMx+wF1rnu9mLDG3VGwdjQuhZLyaywCEIXDp48IOTvG0MOmeYjc6QyN9RCs7YMrTsI+e1Nw1sfJW8TAZJGteTtaMRw7AztRaW1bXUQeo/IWopXUZfQy5Rs2vqd11Hm/OsqzYqi6XaFbsSp5JwwPamtSmprUpjkSCkFEKQUSQOS3JjlXW+3YhxW5XadQ/ddjFydkRnJRV2NmeGipIA1nMs1fV8EgsiqAchfmPo6t6ZanOflcSfnQFxPslc+RW6dKMeZFOpWb4Rm/qRc4NGn1DWtAGBoDRmAAG4CiayFrcw3nSVB6fOe4ScF4Po2mvP2/sn4EWA/UrS/MbQXMb6dQ0jrkb2Kvtxx3YoFa80AZyTkAHzpW+uywiP6tZRQ0PKyboiHlw/wC6YxuKRWnaNvzgsaeN3+dmuQhCyzVBCEIApcKrr5eDIKvYcZusinOb1jLvAWNsD6jk3ZwKDaF6YsnhJcNCZohte0aNbhs4bs1qhUXysq16bvvRTWIlr6HWr1izjHk5a1OtXdhmBFNKfUXZXgzvamtSmplQBU5BpOhIY9EwpBZ288JA04sVHHS45uoaVm7ZhVK05ZnA6mj4BMjQnIg68UeiuKzlreHPcRmJNFm7LhG6XJypfra6odvoVbWa3MdsO1OhScMlerV38HRRKenOSXqYoQ9cVtlxW7Suq0ShoqVSWmUuNexdIlrgrCzlHTyEBsIDsvjuqG78zqDXRbvBmFzsa0vBBlAEbTnbC2uL1uJLjvGpZTBDBcykTTCkYytB8P8A9dunMvRwqWomr2Ro6WDtdghCFULgIQhAAhCEAZ6+cF45SXxERPznxHHaBmO0dix9ubNZ3Uk5Ruo5S07jmXqKi9gIoQCNRyhWaeplHh8orVNLGXK4Z5X/AMRS6CTtOTguW0XhNLkc9x1DLTsXp8lw2RxqbPDXyAOCfZbugj6OKNh1hoB7aJvxUOoifhJ9yPO7twVtM2cck0+E7IepudX9m+jyxAd05SU6auLB1BlD61r0JMtVUeHb7D4aaEc8mJvD6MbA8dz5aB2cOa8uofTqstemDd42SpLPrkQ8OId2A+1H4XVVevoXYaqosu/3Oy08JdWPFLBfodzWSAkZCx2R42FpoQu196v1AL068bjsk/T2eCYjMXxteRuJFQl2fByxM72zxD0QR1A5k74uHgrvRvpnmVksc9odSNjnnXTmjecwW0uLAuOMh89JHZwzwBv8bhvWrYwAUAAAzAZApJFTUylwuBtPSxjy+QAQhCrloEIQgD//2Q==">
</div>
```

P.S - New to JS/Jquery

code copied from - [Stopping fixed position scrolling at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point)

Thanks a lot

Comment: sorry, followto scrolls image after 2550px have passed, so i dont see the difference with followfrom,   do you speak about position of image?

Comment: Here i entered the code, as you can see when scrolling starts the image becomes fixed and stops scrolling after 2550px have passed so is there a way when the image starts to move when i have scrolled lets say 200px ?

Comment: sorry again, i have to misunderstand something, but when you begin to scroll down, the image starts to move up only after 2550px , so look the log i have added,  you say the inverse..., if you want to scroll after 200px, why dont do followto(200px) ?

Comment: Followto 200 will scroll the image till 200 px i want it to start scrolling after 200px have crossed

Comment: last comment are you speaking when the image scrolls down and you scroll up the mouse?

Comment: When i scroll the entire webpage that is 4000px in height, if you change the value from 2550 to 200 , the image will only scroll down with mouse scroll till 200 px.

Comment: you mean your image starts hidden over the top?

Comment: i mean when you scroll down the page the bottle starts moving with you till the followTo(2550) okay ?. So, how to make the image start moving after you have scrolled 200px instead of scrolling 1px ?

Comment: i give up..i dont understant your logic and i am not alone, To help you , people have to understand your process and its not the case. 1) what is the initial position of image 2) what do you want and what happens when you scroll down the mouse 3) what do you want and what happens when you scroll up the mouse... you have to understant all is linked you cant have followTo and FollowFrom in same time as there are described. I suggest you to rebuild more precisely your question.

Comment: I cant have follow From and follow to at same time ? Why ?

Comment: because without modifying the code of followingTo you'll have interaction between the function..

Comment: Sorry to irritate you, I want to make it like that followFrom(200) and followTo(2500) in the same function, thats not possible ?

Comment: you dont irritate me, but i dont understant you and you dont understant me..

Comment: In the code you can see that pos value is **2550**, right ? Which then goes into **if-else** loop to see if the **scrolltop** is greater than **pos** as we scroll down/up. okay ?

Now, i want is that it checks it in a way that **200 > scrolltop > 2550**
So, if you scrolled 200px down it will then initate that if else loop.

If i am still not able to make you understand i am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this piece of code:

200 > scrolltop > 2550  => scrolltop < 200 || scrolltop > 2550, but i doubt the result is what you want

```js
var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function(down, up) {
  var scrollup = true;
  var $this = this,
    $window = $(windw);

  $window.scroll(function(e) {
    console.log($window.scrollTop());
    if ($window.scrollTop() < down || $window.scrollTop() > up) {
      $this.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: up
      });
    } else {
      $this.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 100,
        width: 260.25,
        bottom: 50
      });
    }
  });
};
$('#bottle').followTo(200, 2550);
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#bottle {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <img id="bottle" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxATEBUSExISEhUVEBUSEhUYFxgVEhYVFxEWFxUSFhUYHSggGBolHRUVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGy4gHSUrLS03LSstKy0wLS0tLS0tLS0rLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0rKy0tKy0tLy0tKy0tLS0tLTUrLf/AABEIAT4AnwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAACAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwIFBgQHAQj/xABMEAABAwECCQUMCAMGBwAAAAABAAIDEQQFBhIhMUFRYXGxEyIzgZEjMkJScnOCobLB0fAHFGJ0krPS4RWjtCU1U2OiwhY0Q4OT4vH/xAAaAQACAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwIEBQEG/8QALBEAAgEDBAECBQQDAAAAAAAAAAECAxExBBIhQVETIhQyYXHwQoGhsTNS8f/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A9xQhCABCEIAEIQgAQuG8b4s0FBNPFETmDnAOO5uc9SqpMOLvGaUu3Rv4luVMjRqS5jFv9iLkllmjQsjL9Ithb/jO3M+JC5X/AEoWEf8ATtH4WfrTloq7/QyPqw8m4QsGfpUsP+Fafws9718Z9K9gJyxWpu0sj90hXfgdR/oznrQ8m9QsXH9KF1+FJKzfFIfYBVpYMN7smIDLZBU5Gte7k3E6g2ShrsSZUKkPmi1+xNTi8M0CEISiQIQhAAhCEACEIQAIQhAAhCEAeIYbWet52l3+Yzr7hGqZzaaT1GmjaCtFhqP7QtHnG/lMWfk+HAr1mn/xR+y/ozp/M/uckvlO7AdG8LkkB8Y6fBGgeUuqb48AuWTP+L2VaivqJZDF+0c/ij9S+PA0Y2auUj4KXxHBfP0niVK31OXEujNDX36qrjnFW5hozDWD8F3zOybyOBXDL3vUODlR1PgdTP0pgL/ddh+4Wb8hivFR4C/3XYfuFm/IYrxeXn8zNIEIQogCEIQAIQhAAhCEACEIQB4zhqf7QtHlt/JYs/J8OBXtGFl02aSzzSSQxue2CQteWjlAQwkUfnz7V5bZLkjkB50jaEUy1GbavR6PUqdJcYsjK1NSNKptffJnZvjwC5ZM/wCL2VsH4ItNO7SZa+LqH2Sq+8cFsQVErjnz00+ir0K8XwivKvBK7M78RwUHPAHoniVorowW5Z1HSubQVyU0DaF0zYDRtA7tLm1N+C7PURT29nI14SjuT4MY99T1jgVzzOGL1Dg5Pv8As/IyuY1ziBTKc/e7N69p+jrBC7nXfZrQ+ywySvha97njlOfrAfUN6gKLP1lX047n2XtOt/KNLgL/AHXYfuFm/IYrxfAKZAvq883d3NAEIQuACEIQAIQhAAhCEACEJdonYxpe9wa1oJc4mgAGckoAzn0jXC+2WF0TJRGWuE3OJEb8QE4jyKkDKHVpkLWleZXE2WJmLI98b6muM3HZQZueMn+pbO88OrNMXRUe2OtMYg8+hyGgygbD16hzWb6pIQGSipzDGFew5Vraac6VPbJcZMzU7asuLMpv424OLaxPxdIdStQDmyrpa2S0tIHJsoK5yVq4roYRna7e0FfDcTfBEY3NA4J/xdNYVmUnoqjzyvBibPLJZnEnk35CM5HuSp71dIyrpooRUimMCcn4Stl/w0K1PJn0Krr/AISwCnNbTU0BSlraebXfk5S0M48PHj8Z4Tf9hc6SkPKTYwBLmsLWY1TXnHJmpp0r2f6G8HZbJYSZHtJnk5YMaatj5obQnNj83LTUBlouO/bBZw2rpg12ipFOzSqS4cOPqT8R1ZYS7nAZxreyuSuw59iVqKktRT2x/wCl+hL05Wa4PZELmu23xTxNlheJGPFWuHrBGcEZiDlBXSsZq3DNIEIQuACEIQAIQhAAhC+OcAKnIBlJ0IA+SSBoLiaACpKyF+XgJ+ZTudcx000lfL8vgyuxGGjAe06z8/tXMVylS2+55KVatu9qwIFzQHwGdbWn3KxsFytbzg2Mbmhp9QXRYLOXFW7YSNCnOq1xcXCmnycf1d2pKks8mgHtHxVninUgJaqMY6aZVss8mkHt/dMls7joVg5fYqakOo8h6SXBQz3Xjd9iHeMbiqW8sFoKE4jTrAaG8FunNFKKttEdDRdVaRF00jDXJbZbtkLowX2dzu6M06sbY7bppQ6Ker3dbo542yxODmuFQeII0Ealgb0sdOcBkOcKuuS832GXHZV0Dj3aIaP8xm0cMmojtSHqK/f9k6dXY7PB6whKstoZIxsjHBzXAOa4ZiCmqkXAQhCABCEIAFlMKr5y8iw+Wdvi9WnbuKtsI71FnhJB57uazfTK7qHrprXnbHlxqdKtaelf3Mqamrb2o7YRXbVd8EVXUGXQdp2LlsmRpd6Ld5GU9Q9ZCu7ls/hH5KsTlZFaCuy0ssIa2nanhRCkFTZaR8kORJClKcqiF1HQcoVplU3Jbl0GdFUi0x1G3QpwnJuX1yiRZSTNrUFZy3QYrqaNC1dujoa6+Kpryhxm7QnxYmSF4I3z9Wk5J57hI7JXNFITkOxjjkOo0Okr0deOyNBBBFQRQg6RpC3eA18mWIwvdWSGgqc74jXk3nWchadra6VCvC63Ifp6n6WadCEKqWgQhCAPLcM715W2ujB5sPcxqrkLz2kD0FxRTNHhBZ+Rr32mZ2cunlcRtMrieKsYIXAirSRpp8QtqNNKKRizm3Js0LbWzmNqTQYxyaXZeGKOpaWx21gYAA7XmHxWZsEsRd3pacgyjsFepaSNzdYSakUThNnYLb9kqX1w+J6/2SmgawvpbkVfbHwO3SEvt5r3nr/ZKdejvEHapujXO+JNjGHghKpNdjP4o7xB2pjLYT4NOtc4iXRDGuSjDpBGc2+WSbbi2vMJ6/2SZb3P+GeKZLGuSVo1jtXFGL6OynJCLRfAORzXDqHxXG+8YjnJHUfcuqWWGmUgHWDUdYVZaJYjoL9zU1U4+BXqSKy0WiPGNHDhxXy5r0+r22CWvNMghk1GOUhuXYH4jvRK4Lzsjy6rY3AHMD8SqG9bHII3muLzHHIcuQVGbcpKnF8XJKVnc/SCEuzPLmNcc5aCesVTFkmsCEIQB5fh9dUNlnZMwECd0jnNzgPBaXEbDjk00HfkrrJaWHM4cD6104e3wy2TCKIZIHyMxjme6oDqDQAWUB0rPxQub3wpw7Vr0k9i3ZMmq473twbe6Dzq7a+paBk4OdoWIuYHQSNxI4LQQ2lw0135UmpC7J05cF60x+KOwL65kZGYdiq47YdQT22zZ60lxY5SQ51jjPg9hI4FQN1wnwXfjf8AqX0WvYpi17PX+yLz8nfZ4Em6IPFd/wCST9Sj/DIRma78b/1J7rV9n1/slOtTvFH4j8EXn5/k41Dx/Ao2CLxa7y48SlmyxjMxg9EKb53/AGR1E+8LmdI/S4dTacSVL3eSLt4G41MgApqoKLlkUZXE+EeHBc0g69+XiupEGzjvjR861DBi44rXOWy5WMbjObofzgA07M9VG84yWggKODl/sscxdI2rHgNeRnaMauPTTTV/8MrPa9uSMXHct2D1hC+Ar6s81AQhCAPBbL00nnZPzHK/gVFZx3V218h/nSD3K9gW1IxkX92WePFysBza26PskKzbZoToeNxrxVfdZ5g3DgFYsVSbdyxBKxL6lHoc/rAK+Gx6nV3invTmprUu7GqKOYWQ6wpCzO2LpCkFHczu1HGbO7YlmB+pvafgrByW5G4HFFe6B/2e0/BINnfpc3qaeNVYuSHqSkyDijgfZ/tH1fBJdC0a+0ldsi5pFJNkGjjto5hWKvrvT5J4LbWzvD86Vi73HMfsYeIHvTqWRNTB7lYeiZ5tvshPSLD0TPNt9kJ6zXk1kCEIXDp4VGO69cn9RKrqBVBHdR6f9RKreBbLMbs0dxtrG3yR7IVq2HaqrB7o2+SOAV21U5vktQwREZUwFNqic6XcYj6FIKIUguEgcluTHJbkAxLkh6e5IcFJEGc8i5pF1PadSQ6IqSFM4bZ3h+dKx15jucvmv97FsrcKNPzpWPvAdzm8wfzI06llCamGe22Homebb7IT0iw9EzzbfZCes55NZAhCFw6eHyDuo8l39RKrWFVkw7q3yHf1Eqs4Fs9GO8mjwe6NvkjgFdtVJg90bfJHAK7aqVTJZhgY1ROdSaonOljT6FIKIUgg6DktyY5LcgGJcoN0qblBuldIMW9JenPSXrpBlXeHeu3+9ZC3Duc33c/mRrX3h3rt/vWStfRz/d3e2xWKeUInhntNh6Jnm2+yE9IsPRM8232QnrOeTVQIQhcOniVo6VvkO/PlVlAq209K3yHfnyKygWx0Y7yaTB/o2+SOAV01U1xDmDyRwCuWqnUyWYYGNUTnUmqJzpY0+hSCiFIIOg5LcmOS3IBiXKDdKm5QbpXSDFvSXpz0l66QZV3h3rt/vWTtXRT/AHd3ttWsvDvXb/esnauin+7u9pqsUxEz2iw9EzzbfZCekWHomebb7IT1nPJqoEIQuHTxO09K3yHfnSKxgVdaT3Vvku/OkVjAtjox3k0t0uo3s4BWzJQqe7e87OCsGKpNcliD4O5pXw50lqaEuw1EgpBRCkFwkDktyY5LcgGJcoN0qblBuldIMW9JenPSXrpBlXeHeu3+9ZS09FP93d7TVq7w712/3rJ2o9yn8wfaarFMRM9osPRM8232QnpFh6Jnm2+yE9ZzyaqBCELh08Pe7uo9MfzpFawKmY6sp2OeP5rlcwLZeDHeTR3b3nZwVgxV92d586lYMVSeSxDA9qa1KamtS2NRIKQUQpBRJA5LcmOS3IBiXKDdKm5IeukGD0h6+SFc0ikkLbOa8O9d86VkLce5TbYiPWFrbZ3hWOvN3c5NrDwT6eRM8Ht9h6Jnm2+yE9IsPRM8232QnrOeTVQIQhcOnhLG0tErdU8reyRw9yu4FaYa4ONhkda2HmPkrI2nevecrtoc7sLtRyVFkla7MQdxWvGanFNGRODhKzNHdLqsVmxUtwO5lOtXTFXnkdDA9qa1KamtSmORIKQUQpBRJA5LcmOS3IBiXJD09yQ9SRBnPIuaRdMi5pFJCmcduPMKxd8HmO8k+yVrr1lAZlNPmiTgtg79bk5VxpDHIMbXI4UdyY1NzVOo0GeobCSj7ngW4uT2o9Os7KMaNTQOwJiELONUEIQgDzD6QMIJJpHWSLFDI30kPhPe3QDmAB0a259eUs7CDlBB9alDLj2iV/jTyO/FK4+9XcbARQgEbVswiqcUkY85OcrsbcFukZQA4w1OGMOonKOorVxXiw99HTa0+4qmum7ojnDm6iDXtB+KuBdfiyNdsPNKRUcWxsFKx0stcR8cbwDwTROzxvcuE2CUeD2UK+cm4ZwUnauhu5otGvGsdqkHDWFWAKQXNpJSLBzhrHakunZ4ze1cyg4oUQchslobrPUCeAXK+1DQ1x6gOJXx8rfGHaEkvBzBx3NdTtpRSURbkV9931yOLzMYuJpV1KUpU5toVFLhBM7Nit3DL/qqm4btcGxOpTnuGWmkA/7VnbNjOIAyk6BlV6jSg4J2K1SUrjLdaXPdznF281V7gThU6yyiF4BhlkaHa2OdRokB1d7Uahsy0dvs7mAFwptyH1j5yKnthqDuPBdlTjJbXgjCbi9yP0qhKssmNG13jMa7tAKasM2wQhCAPALqFXnyj7RWlhBGQ5FU3BFS0yDxXyDrEhb8Vf2sc8eSOJWzJ82MdLi5bXUOb87VZsVbdfe9ismKpPI+GB7CmgpTU1qUxyJBfcQagvgUguEiDo2+KOwJZhb4rewJ7ktyLnGhLkh6e5IepIizGfSO7uMQ08sT1BhrxCrcEYW4hkfXK7FyZ6CmQbzwX3De1iWYMblbECK/aJGN2UA6ium5IsWzsGwu7XE+9aUVtopFOo+S1viyxSWZ2KAKAmtMuQaVkMG7I2U2hjgCRY5sWuWjw3I7eKrU8rSOUa4z20oOKpsCI+62t+hsEw6yW/ApV3GLOwtJo9juj/l4fMx+wF1rnu9mLDG3VGwdjQuhZLyaywCEIXDp48IOTvG0MOmeYjc6QyN9RCs7YMrTsI+e1Nw1sfJW8TAZJGteTtaMRw7AztRaW1bXUQeo/IWopXUZfQy5Rs2vqd11Hm/OsqzYqi6XaFbsSp5JwwPamtSmprUpjkSCkFEKQUSQOS3JjlXW+3YhxW5XadQ/ddjFydkRnJRV2NmeGipIA1nMs1fV8EgsiqAchfmPo6t6ZanOflcSfnQFxPslc+RW6dKMeZFOpWb4Rm/qRc4NGn1DWtAGBoDRmAAG4CiayFrcw3nSVB6fOe4ScF4Po2mvP2/sn4EWA/UrS/MbQXMb6dQ0jrkb2Kvtxx3YoFa80AZyTkAHzpW+uywiP6tZRQ0PKyboiHlw/wC6YxuKRWnaNvzgsaeN3+dmuQhCyzVBCEIApcKrr5eDIKvYcZusinOb1jLvAWNsD6jk3ZwKDaF6YsnhJcNCZohte0aNbhs4bs1qhUXysq16bvvRTWIlr6HWr1izjHk5a1OtXdhmBFNKfUXZXgzvamtSmplQBU5BpOhIY9EwpBZ288JA04sVHHS45uoaVm7ZhVK05ZnA6mj4BMjQnIg68UeiuKzlreHPcRmJNFm7LhG6XJypfra6odvoVbWa3MdsO1OhScMlerV38HRRKenOSXqYoQ9cVtlxW7Suq0ShoqVSWmUuNexdIlrgrCzlHTyEBsIDsvjuqG78zqDXRbvBmFzsa0vBBlAEbTnbC2uL1uJLjvGpZTBDBcykTTCkYytB8P8A9dunMvRwqWomr2Ro6WDtdghCFULgIQhAAhCEAZ6+cF45SXxERPznxHHaBmO0dix9ubNZ3Uk5Ruo5S07jmXqKi9gIoQCNRyhWaeplHh8orVNLGXK4Z5X/AMRS6CTtOTguW0XhNLkc9x1DLTsXp8lw2RxqbPDXyAOCfZbugj6OKNh1hoB7aJvxUOoifhJ9yPO7twVtM2cck0+E7IepudX9m+jyxAd05SU6auLB1BlD61r0JMtVUeHb7D4aaEc8mJvD6MbA8dz5aB2cOa8uofTqstemDd42SpLPrkQ8OId2A+1H4XVVevoXYaqosu/3Oy08JdWPFLBfodzWSAkZCx2R42FpoQu196v1AL068bjsk/T2eCYjMXxteRuJFQl2fByxM72zxD0QR1A5k74uHgrvRvpnmVksc9odSNjnnXTmjecwW0uLAuOMh89JHZwzwBv8bhvWrYwAUAAAzAZApJFTUylwuBtPSxjy+QAQhCrloEIQgD//2Q==">
</div>
```