# How do I make image stop at a certain point from a fixed location. (Example link provided)

Tags: javascript, parallax

I am trying to make this parallax effect where when you scroll down, the image follows to the next location, then stops at said location(or destination). Once it reaches its destination, I want it to stay there and as you continue to scroll down, The image cannot continue past the destination set on it and I want it to scroll off the window, not stick at the top. Although I feel like this would be a fairly basic parallax task, unfortunately I am new to parallax.

```
<div class="myimg">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pzhXqfp.png" class="self" onclick="scrollWin()">
</div>
```

```
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollTo(0,1);
}
```

on scrollTo, on the Y axis, I have tried 0, 1, 50, 100, 500, and all kinds of numbers, but even at the lower numbers, it will scroll the entire page.

Edit: I found a perfect example: https://www.apple.com/ph/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-mini .

I would like to replicate this exact thing with the iPad. It scrolls down to a certain point on the Y axis and once it hits its destination, it no longer moves down the page. I have also tried the following, which is something I found from another Stack Overflow question, but this one is sticking to to top, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. Close though!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".myimg").css("top",Math.max(0,250-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

Comment: any example website showing this effect or do you have a better way to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgIwjLg4ONk

at the 1:00 mark you will see the kitten parachuting to the ground and it stops on the ground. Lets say I replicated this, but unlike in this example, the ground was not the end of my webpage. Lets say I still had an additional 1000px of content to display after this effect. I would need it to stop on the ground, not continue the length of the webpage. In this example, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902822/stopping-fixed-position-scrolling-at-a-certain-point

The first answer was close, but it sticks at the top.

Comment: I just want the image to scroll down lets say 150px, stop at the destination, and when I continue to scroll down past 150px, The image no longer follows and it leaves the window as normal.

Comment: I just found a perfect example: https://www.apple.com/ph/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-mini

Here, the iPad scrolls down with the page until it hits a certain point and it stops in place. If you continue to scroll down, it scrolls as normal as if it were never moving in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example website (https://www.apple.com/ph/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-mini) that you provided it is not a parallax effect but a sticky element in which it sticks to the screen at a given position until it reaches the end of its parent's height.
To create this effect just write the following `.html` and `.css` code:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50vh;
  padding-bottom: 200vh;
}

.parent {
  height: 100vh;
}

.sticky-box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sticky-box"></div>
</div>
```

We define a `div` element with `position: sticky` with `top: 0` for it to stick in top of the screen. Notice: The `sticky-box` travels the full height of the parent in the fixed position (so we define `height: 100vh` in the parent). More information in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

Comment: Ooooohhhhh its a sticky, never heard of that before now. Thank you so much!