# How to make child div expand to parent div

Tags: css

Hi i am having trouble trying to get my child div expand to the height of the parent div that it is inside of.

Here is the css for the parent div

```
#wrapper #content {
    border: 1px ridge #999;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 1000px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

And here is the css for the child div

```
.tab_container {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px ridge #999;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas what i can do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery. Please check the example code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Height in jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var height = $("#content").height();
    $(".tab_container").height(height);
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper #content {
    border: 1px ridge #999;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 1000px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    float: left;
}
.tab_container {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px ridge #999;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="tab_container">Tab Container</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou, this method worked perfectly, for some reason though it adjusted the div above aswell, not sure why but i managed to adjust it to fit, so thanks a lot for the help

Comment: If you found answers are useful, you can vote up or even can choose the right answer by clicking the correct mark.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the folowing style: (Inspired by this question: [CSS - Expand float child DIV height to parent's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height))

```
#content {
    border: 1px ridge #999;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 1000px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative; /* added */
    width: 100%; /* added */
}

.tab_container {
    border: 1px ridge orange; /* added */
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px ridge #999;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; /* added */
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aMFAX/)

Answer (score 0):

You have `margin-bottom` set on both elements. With the child having a bottom margin, it will always be smaller by that amount. Removing the `margin-bottom` style might bring it a little closer.

Answer (score -1):

The height of the parent is auto.  The 100% of the child results in it also being defined as auto, and auto results in size to content.

You can try adding a fixed height to the parent which **might** work or put enough content in the child to stretch it; that **will**  work.