# DIVs won't stretch all the way down to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, html, layout, stretch

I apologize if this is a trivial question but I can't seem to figure it out. I have [this website](http://jsfiddle.net/m6DmQ/14/) and I need the navigation bar on the side, and the rectangle all the way on the right (The one with the "ContentExtender" class) to stretch down to the bottom of the physical page (well, the ContentExtender only needs to stretch as far as the content so it blends, but that's another story). What is the simplest way to do this? I looked it up and found setting the Body's height to 100% should work, but it didn't. I know that's a lot of code to look through, so here is the actual important parts of the code (anything prefixed with "cc" was just an easy way of commenting them out):

```
.ContentExtender {
    background-image: url(bgblack.png);
    min-height: 10px;
    ccmin-width: 200px;
    ccwidth:100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 1010px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.MainParent {
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color:rgba(70,70,70,.7);
    min-height: 600px;
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    z-index:100;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at your jsFiddle?

Comment: lol what's wrong with it?

Comment: You can't just refer to bgblack.png from jsFiddle.

Comment: Yeah, I edited it after I put the link, then forgot to update the link, my apologies

Comment: you have unnecessary tables. of which one of them is wrapping your sidebar. tables are evil.

Comment: It was easier to just use tables then figure out how to use DIVS correctly for that portion, but it doesn't affect the rest of the page though

Answer (score 0):

You need to give html, body { height: 100%; } plus make any other parents of the element you want to have `height: 100%;`, `height: 100%;`

Comment: I already tried that, it just sets it to the size of the viewable area instead of the whole page

Comment: Well, then your page is not as tall as your screen, but it is still at 100%. You can make anything in your page `height: 9999px` and you will see.

Comment: The page is much taller than the screen, but the navigation bar and the ContentExtender only stretch down as far as the screen goes?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem where I could not extend to the top of the window, which may be similar.  I set:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

In your case, it may be another element.  I have seen where all possible elements are intentionally set to a 0 margin, and then the margins desired are re-implemented.

Comment: I already have my body set to that, and setting them all to 0px; didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

seems like there's a small error in your code try editing your

```
.ContentExtender
```

and change it to

```
#ContentExtender
```

Then you will be able to fix it, if this method doesn't work try setting the background CSS on the HTML tag of the Content extender like below

```
html{
height:100%;    
background:#ccc url(bgblack.png);
```

}

the above is an example, so please improvise

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is linked to the fact that a child div cannot directly dictate the behaviour of a parent.

Try one of these on your parent div:

```
overflow: auto;

display: table;
```

Or in the child div:

```
display: table-row;
```

When you try it, experiment with omitting the "height: blabla" attribute.

Similar problem solved: [1]: [CSS - Expand float child DIV height to parent's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height)

Comment: Whenever I did that, it just pushes everything apart, like puts huge gaps between all of my navigation bar links