# Same height divs?

Tags: html, css

I have a the following:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="sectionA">
   </div>
   <div class="sectionB">
   </div>
</div>
```

Section A has a red background, Section B has a blue background.

Section A has lots of text in it, making it quite tall, section B does not have much text in it.

How can I make it so that Section A and B are the same height as the parent?

Comment: what do you mean same height as their parent ? each has its own height and their parent  have the sum of their both heights. what do you mea n?

Comment: Same height as the parent, or the same height as the taller of A and B?

Comment: The parent being the container.

Comment: Have you tried any CSS yet? If so, please post it.

Comment: What type of browser support are you looking for? IE7? Within `sectionA` or `sectionB`, do to you want the text to be aligned vertically? Does the parent `.container` have a specified height?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can give the childs the same heights as the parent. This will work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
   <div class="sectionA">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
   </div>
   <div class="sectionB">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.container{height:200px;width:500px;overflow:hidden}
.sectionA{position:relative;float:left;width:250px;background:blue;height:100%}
.sectionB{position:relative;float:left;width:250px;background:red;height:100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind about using jquery,

```
    $('.sectionB').css('height', $('.sectionA').outerHeight() );
```

sectionB css height is set by the sectionA outerHeight.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ovisiv/1/edit).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in dynamically, I think you need to use jquery/javascript to handle otherwise you can use height property. Use the suitable highest value for both sections.

Answer (score 0):

**Faux-Column Effect Using `<div>` and CSS**

One way of doing this involves adding an extra element as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="sectionA">
        <p>Text of A... can be on a red background.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor... and long text block.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionB">
        <p>Text of B... can be on a blue background.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am going to add an extra element `<div class="backdrop">`, which you could replace with an pseudo-element if so desired.

The appropriate CSS is as follows:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

.sectionA {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    padding: 1%;
}
.sectionB {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    padding: 1%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 3000px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The parent `.container` element is given the background-color for the left-hand side column (red), with `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative`.

The two child/column elements are placed using `float: left`, and given a relative width of 48% and padding of 1% (you can adjust these measurements as needed).

Finally, `.backdrop` is positioned absolutely and placed to the right hand side of the parent container.  I set it to have a tall height to make sure that it stretches beyond any expected height of any of the two columns, and declare the `background-color: blue`.

Use `z-index` to move the floated `.sectionB` to be painted above `.backdrop`.  Note that you need set position `.sectionB` relatively so that the z-index value takes effect.

Since `.container` uses `overflow:hidden`, the tall backdrop element is clipped so you can the effect that you want.

**Using a background-image** could also work.  You could create a background image with the left hand side red and the right hand side blue, and tile it vertically with position top and center, just making the width is wide enough to accommodate any expected page width.

The main advantage of using `div.backdrop`is that you can alter the color scheme using CSS properties alone without changing the background image.

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/yejss/