# Responsive CSS Menu to match height of parent

Tags: css

I want to make my navigation fill the space of the header vertically. I've tried 100% height with no luck. 
If you see here on the development site: http://inspiredworx-labs.com/sites/mannings/ the homepage menu item has a red background that does not stretch/fill the full height of the header.
How can I achieve it, so that all menu items fill the height, even if the height changes?

Thanks

Comment: This solved my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to achieve this is a bit tricky but very solid.

Here is a nice and clear explanation :

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase padding as below. So, it will look as you need the updates.

```
#masthead .nav ul li a{
  padding: 19px 15px;
}
```

Comment: If I add the 19px top and bottom margins, and the header height increases, then the menu won't fit flush again. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @HuwRowlands - To stretch/fill the full height of header in responsive layout, you can make update as below.

`#masthead .nav {
  display: block;
}`

Comment: Doesn't change anything? Thanks

Comment: @HuwRowlands - I just checked and in responsive layout menu items are not displaying as the position is changed to absolute for `#masthead .nav`.

1) so I think you need to update it from `absolute` to `relative` to view menu items as it was there previously.

2) `#masthead .nav {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      font-weight: normal;
      position: relative;
}`

here, you need to update css as `display: block;`. As I'm not able to give screenshot over here. Let me know if I'm assuming correct or not.