# CSS3 display: table-cell & float?

Tags: css-float, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I've got a long div container set to `display:table` and & divs within it set to `display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle`.

I'm really happy with the results of vertical alignment, but:

- I don't know the width of these 3 divs,
- I want one of them to be on the very right side of div container (minus padding of course),
- `float: right` doesn't work with `display: table-cell`.

Here's an example (I want to float the golden divs to the right). I can't use JS. I need it to work in IE7+, or IE8+ if impossible for IE7. Any hints / ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/cZ7Th/2/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if this works with IE7 or 8, but I have done this by combining `width: 1px`, `width: auto` and `white-space: nowrap`. Define all cells in the table layout as one-pixel wide, but prevent wrapping; then add an empty padding cell before the ones you want to float right.

http://jsfiddle.net/wZ96P/

Seems to work with the modern versions of Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and IE, at least.

Comment: This totally solved my problem. It worked for me without having to set `width: 1px` as long as I included the div with `width: auto;`

Answer (score 6):

For this vertical align doesn't work:

```
<div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; float: right">...</div>
```

But for this it works for me:

```
<div style="float: right">
  <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[When float!=none then display = block](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visuren.html#float-position)