# Nested DIVs width % height

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #left {
      float: left;
    }

    #left_top, #left_bottom {
      height: 50%; /* Not working... */
    }

    #right {
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="left_top">A</div>
    <div id="left_bottom">B</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    Content
    <br />
    Content
    <br />
    Content
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The two DIVs with the IDs left_top and left_bottom should take up 50% of the height of the surrounding DIV (#left). How can I make that happen?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: My guess is to add #left height property

Comment: It;s working http://jsbin.com/xavog/1/edit

Comment: @mohamedrias - only because you changed the CSS to provide a specific height for `#left`

Comment: In deed it is - but since the height of the right div is flexible and the left div shoudl have the same height, I cannot provide a px-value here. And 100% does not work...

Comment: @SW4 i have removed all height & width. http://jsbin.com/xavog/1/edit i feel its occupying 50% height by default.

Comment: i cant understand what he wants -.-

Comment: Check out this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height)

Comment: You cannot set a percentage height unless it's parent has a specified height set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming `left` is the same height as `content`, however this isnt how floated divs work.

You can see this in effect [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/C3jVt/).

One way would be to give both `left` and `right` the same specified `height`.

The alternative, for a more flexible layout would be to use CSS tables, and not floats:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/C3jVt/3/)

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    display:table;
    height:0%; /* to provide a base 'autofit' height */
}
#left, #right {
    display:table-cell;
}
#left_top, #left_bottom {
    height: 50%;
}
```