# Setting the height of child to parent div by using only CSS and without JS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set child div height 100% to parent div. As it is a style thing, I don't want to use `JS/JQ`, this should be done in `CSS`. Here is the [Link of Code](http://codepen.io/iiison/pen/RNzjOg) and This is snippet:

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a{
  float: left;
  background: red;
  padding-right: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}
.b{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 29px;
}
.c{
  height: 300px;
  width: 90px;
  background: grey;
  float: left;
}
```

**Please Don't use `Position: Absolute/Relative`, that is not an option for me in my current code structure**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Force Child Div to 100% of Parent's Div Without Specifying Parent's Height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh) - also possible duplicate [CSS - Expand child DIV height to parent's height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height) - Note that the accepted answers are not always the most informative answers.

Answer (score 1):

`height:100%` only works on an element if the height of the parent element is known (and/or calculable).

If the parent of `.a` doesn't have a specified/inherited height, then `height: 100%` has no effect on it (and thus, `height: 100%` on `.b` also has no effect because `.a` doesn't have a specified/calculable height).

Alternatively, you could do this really easily with flexbox (browser support is IE10+ and everything else):

```css
.a{
  float: left;
  background: red;
  padding-right: 1px;
  display: flex;
}
.b{
  background: blue;
  width: 29px;
}
.c{
  height: 300px;
  width: 90px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way out other than using absolute position?

Comment: @BharatSoni What do you mean? Adam is not using absolute position -  he's using [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

Comment: @showdev What I am saying is, neither the Height is not specified nor using position absolute is option for me. so is there any other way to fix this

Comment: @BharatSoni Adam's solution shown above neither specifies the parent height nor uses absolute position.

Comment: Now he edited the answer :) :) and it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the wrapper div to act as a `display: table`, and the children to behave as `display: table-cell`. This would equal the children's height:

```css
.a{
  float: left;
  background: red;
  display: table;
}
.b{
  display: table-cell;
  background: blue;
  width: 29px;
}
.c{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 300px;
  width: 90px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing it, rather than **floats** and `display: table` would be `display: flex`.

You can use `display: flex` on the container and `flex: grow` on the child.

Here is a link that explains the process in more detail:

https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/