# How to place a div to the height of it's parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using **Bootstrap 3.0.2**. Want to stretch a div to the height of it's parent div. Not interested to set with a script. Is there any way to do so? Please see the fiddle. Here I want to stretch the blue container to the height of parent green container.

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatCop/jpes2wry/)

```
<div class="row border-green">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="border-red">
            aaaa<br>
            bbbb<br>
            cccc
        </div>
        <div class="border-red">
            dddd
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 border-blue">
        eeee<br>
        ffff<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height

Comment: My fork: http://jsfiddle.net/6wpfr18y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a class to your parent div: `equal-height`

Add this to your CSS:

```
.equal-height {
    display: table;
}
.equal-height > div {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jpes2wry/3/

Answer (score 3):

`Flexible box` solution works fine for your problem. Add `display: flex` to the parent element.

For current readers, Compatibility table: [Can I use Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

For future readers, Flexible box is the way to go!

```css
.border-red {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #FF0000;
}
.border-blue {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #2E2EB8;
}
.border-green {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #00CC00;
}
.equal-height {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row border-green equal-height">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="border-red">
      aaaa
      <br>bbbb
      <br>cccc
    </div>
    <div class="border-red">
      dddd
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 border-blue">
    eeee
    <br>ffff
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this does not work with IE 9 and earlier, IE 10 requires a prefix like `-ms-flex`. While IE 11 fully supports the flex-property. See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. I see someone down voted for the incompatibility with IE.

Comment: I upvoted for the simplicity of the solution. I know i am not supposed to express my opinion here but, people using old IE versions should be punished

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen Agreed! Anyone using IE9 is wilfully holding back the web. Those people can live without a full-height section.

Answer (score 1):

I just add height to your codes and it works, just try:

```
.border-red {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: #FF0000;
 }
.border-blue {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: #2E2EB8;
   height: 100%;
}
.border-green{
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: #00CC00;
   height: 100px;
 }
```