# Auto height div with javascript or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On this page here [enter link description here](http://bit.ly/1fhGdI0) you see the right sidebar,i would like this column has the same height as the main central column.
I think this requires javascript or css but I do not know how.
This is a Joomla CMS but i can add some code in a module.

Thanks.

Comment: Try solving the problem with CSS, first. Maybe you should take a look at some tutorials like this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Expand child DIV height to parent's height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height)

Comment: Hello @alynioke I saw that you had removed your solution, why, this was usefull for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with CSS alone, using a faux-column technique, here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1r8xygnL/. I updated the id's and CSS below to reflect the id's on the page you linked to.

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="faux-col-right"><!-- this is just for the background //--></div>

    <div id="center">
    <!-- center column content goes here //-->
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    <!-- right column content goes here //-->
    </div>
</div>

#main {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
}

.faux-col-right {
    background: #cccccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 69.047619047619%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#right {
    width: 30.952380952381%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#center {
    width: 69.047619047619%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hello your solution is the better but if like on this page http://bit.ly/1RK5Dzy there is no left column, it is a problem.

Comment: Thanks i have found by changing css only for this page

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript or JQuery at all. You can fix this with some CSS. An almost identical question is answered here:

[CSS - Expand float child DIV height to parent's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height)

Comment: Good answer. I'm not certain this solution would work if the right column content exceeds the left column content. The solution I posted should work in either context.

Comment: Yes this solution don't work if the right column content exceeds the center column

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript.
This page includes jQuery. So add this to your page

```
<script>
$(function(){
  jQuery('#right .inner').
  css('height', jQuery('#center .inner').height())
})
```

You have to use the inner_element. Because the background is applied to inner.
If we change the height of $('#right'), you will not see it.

Comment: Hello, thanks but this don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using jquery, You can use `.height()` to get the height of min content

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mainHeight = $('#center').height();
  alert(mainHeight);
});
```

Comment: Thanks i try to add this code on the page but this don't work.