# Force img height 100% of parent height

Tags: html, css

Have this image inside a section which has to be forced to have the exact same height of the section height. I worked this out but it doesn't seems to work on resizing.

Code I have

**HTML**

```
  <section id="header-bg">
    <img src="images/background.png">
  </section>
```

**CSS**

```
$header-bg-top: 80px;
$header-bg-height: 620px;
#header-bg {
  position: relative;
  top: $header-bg-top;
  max-height: $header-bg-height;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    img {
      background: url(../images/background.png);
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
```

Result on full screen:
[image]

Result on resized screen:

[image]

I already found a lot on the internet, but this is not working out for me.

[CSS - Expand float child DIV height to parent's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-child-div-height-to-parents-height)

[How to Force Child Div to 100% of Parent's Div Without Specifying Parent's Height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh)

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: Please add your code to fiddle

Comment: Give the parent a height, not only a max-height. Why would you use a background image on the img element? Set the bg at the parent

Comment: @LaxmikantDange sorry for being unclear, updated the post

Comment: Please post your html too

Comment: @FionnaChan, if I give the parant a height it would not scale any more

Comment: @AndrewLyndem updated my post, sorry, don't know why I forgot the html code..

Comment: Try this #header-bg img { height: 100%; width: auto; }

Comment: @FionnaChan scaling then won't working anymore and the with is nog full screen:(

Comment: You are not showing CSS (as stated in your tags).

Comment: In which browser does it not work?

Comment: @connexo, all the code is there? Using google chrome

Comment: Add `#header-bg img { display: block; }`.