# ReactJS Styling a Component to take full screen with background color

Tags: css, reactjs

Is there anyway I can tell React component to take full screen and the background color will be green. The code below does not make the height 100%.

```
var rootStyle = {
  backgroundColor : 'green',
  color : 'white',
  height : '100%'

}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={rootStyle}>
      <Poll />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a pure CSS problem, React does nothing but pass on the style info into the DOM. Also, 100% of what?

Comment: If I link a css file using the <link> tag can I refer to the styles in the css file.

Comment: 100% of the parent right! Parent is the body.

Answer (score 12):

Make the div 100% of the viewport height.

```
var rootStyle = {
  height: '100vh',
  min-height : '100vh'
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add some details about your solution.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not React. React just gets the HTML to the page. 
The problem is that your `body` element is only as big as its content. One way around this is to add this to your css:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654996/2437278)

Comment: This solution helped me. Thanks. Also, I needed to target #root which is the id of the div that React points to in the Index.jsx and make it to have width and height 100% as well.

Answer (score 2):

While answers above might work. The code below solved the issue for me. Then you can style what is inside the App component the way you want.

```
html, body, body > div, .app {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is more of a "make my div block have the full window or parentDOMElement height" than "how to make ReactComponent have the full window or parentDOMElement height".

Here's a post that explains this: [CSS - Expand float child DIV height to parent's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-float-child-div-height-to-parents-height)

The gist of it is that the parent element's `position` needs to be `relative`. Then, the child (i.e. the element you're trying to make have a height of 100% of its container) will actually have a `height` of 100% of its container.

Here's a demo:

```
<body>
<div id="title"></div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    Hi, I am a child
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
    .parent {
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgba(50, 70, 200, 0.3);
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .child {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(50, 70, 200, 0.3);
    }
</style>
```

With that, you just need to Render your React component inside of the `.parent` div and should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootStyle = {
  backgroundColor : 'green',
  color : 'white',
  height : '100vh'
}
```

or

```
var rootStyle = {
  position: absolute,
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootStyle = {
  backgroundColor : 'green',
  color : 'white',
  height : '100%'
}
```

Here you apply this style into only div section so for that you need in include "backgroundColor" property into app.css

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={rootStyle}> // this style apply only its div not full screen
      <Poll />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.css
html,body{backgourd:green}
```